# iOS build status while uploading App to itunes

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

After updating my system from High Sierra to Mojave I am getting an error of " the transport has been detected as having stalled and has been aborted" while uploading App to the Appstore.

Why I am getting this issue, please do help I am stuck with this trouble?

Comment: uploading via Xcode or Application Loader? Please try this answer [unable-to-upload-ios-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240579/unable-to-upload-ios-app-with-application-loader)

Comment: I have tried both, and getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i am assuming your are using application Loader. Please go to Settings -> Advanced and uncheck DAV option. After that try to uploads.Its worked for me through application Loader.

> Also check for your application Loader update if you have any.

I hope it will works !